# Частичное перекрывание изображений при скроллинге

Tags: html5, css3, прокрутка

Предположим, HTML страница состоит из двух изображений, высота каждого `100vh`. То есть сразу после загрузки страницы видно только первое. Как сделать так, чтобы при скроллинге вниз второе изображение налазило на первое и частично перекрывало его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-attachment: fixed`
The background is fixed with regard to the viewport
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp